# selecting dropdown item to get info from a html element is very slow selenium chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from product page in wish.com (https://www.wish.com/c/58b56224d1675a12c859d21c)

when you change the dropdown box item of color or size the price changes so I wanted to scrape all possible combinations of color and size and save the right price for each combination.

I used the following code:

```
    ChromeDriver CD = new ChromeDriver();
    CD.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
    Actions actions = new Actions(CD);

    MessageBox.Show("Start");
    var SC = CD.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id=\"fancy-select-options-size\"]/li");
    var CC = CD.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id=\"fancy-select-options-color\"]/li");
    var PP = CD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"product-content\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]");
    for (int i = 1; i < SC.Count; i++)
    {
        actions.MoveToElement(SC[i]).Click().Perform();
        for(int j=0; j<CC.Count;j++)
        {
             actions.MoveToElement(CC[j]).Click().Perform();
             Debug.Write(i.ToString() + " :: " + j.ToString() + " = " + CD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"product-content\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]").Text + '\n');
        }
    } 
    MessageBox.Show("FINISH");
```

but it turned out to be wrong and running very slow.

Question: Is there anyway to get the data I want faster than that?

Comment: `but it turned out to be wrong` In what way is it wrong?

Comment: it doesn't even click the item.

Comment: can you please help me I am new to C# and stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972665/selecting-dropdown-item-to-get-info-from-a-html-element-is-very-slow-selenium-ch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page design is a hot mess... anyway... when I tackle things like this where actions are repeated, it's best to write functions for the repeatable actions like getting the price, setting the color, etc. Here are the list of functions

```
public static int getNumberOfColorOptions()
{
    return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#fancy-select-color li.fancy-select-option")).size();
}

public static int getNumberOfSizeOptions()
{
    return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#fancy-select-options-size li.fancy-select-option")).size();
}

public static String getPrice()
{
    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.price")).getText();
}

public static void setColorByIndex(int index)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("fancy-select-color")).click();
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#fancy-select-color li.fancy-select-option")).get(index).click();
}

public static void setSizeByIndex(int index)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("fancy-select-size")).click();
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#fancy-select-options-size li.fancy-select-option")).get(index).click();
}
```

and here is the code to loop through the color and size choices and write out the price.

```
String url = "https://www.wish.com/c/58b56224d1675a12c859d21c";
driver.navigate().to(url);

// always start at 1 since the first option is "Choose a XXX..."
for (int sizeIndex = 1; sizeIndex < getNumberOfSizeOptions(); sizeIndex++)
{
    setSizeByIndex(sizeIndex);
    for (int colorIndex = 1; colorIndex < getNumberOfColorOptions(); colorIndex++)
    {
        setColorByIndex(colorIndex);
        System.out.println(getPrice());
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to test the code because you have to sign up for an account but this should get you pretty close. You may need to add some waits in there.